# auto-populating modelform choice field on the basis of selection of other choice field

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-app-engine

I am using django on google app engine on my project.This is my first project so everyday i am finding new problems to face.My modelform is having two fields both having choices.For example, suppose the choice for first form field(lets say field1) in models.py is,

```
TITLE_TYPE = (
    ('A',A),
    ('B',B),
)
```

There are two choices for field two(lets say field2).

```
choice1=(
    (1,'1'),
    (2,'2'),
)

choice2=(
    (3,'3'),
    (4,'4'),
)
```

I want when user select item A in field1,the field2 should be choice1 automatically and when user select B in field1,the field2 should be choice2. Any suggestion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem you describe will need some help on the client side, namely javascript. In general: Attach an event listener to field `A` and set the selected item in `B` accordingly.

Comment: Well it sounds good.But I am using ModelForm to create my form.Is it possible to combine javascript with my ModelForm choice field? As I told I am very new to django and python,so please bear my ignorance.

Comment: there has got to be a way to set a choice field from within django forms